# Elixir. Не могу создать проект

Tags: elixir

Два месяца учил Elixir на Windows. Проблем не было. Проекты создавал командой mix new name_project из командной строки. Решил попробовать Elixir в Линукс. Установил Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon.  Erlang и Elixir установились без проблем, оболочка работает. А вот проект создать не получается, вроде ругается на синтаксис.

Ниже ссылка на снимок окна с ошибкой. На снимке видно, что оболочка Elixir запускается. А проект создать не получается.
https://yapx.ru/v/FW5YD

Answer (score 0):

Похожая ситуация описана [здесь](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2297).

Проблема должна решиться путем обновления версии Erlang OTP.
Версия Elixir, судя по скриншоту, у Вас тоже устаревшая.

[Есть удобный инструмент ASDF](https://elixirgirls.com/install-guides/linux.html), с помощью которого Вы можете управлять версиями Elixir/Erlang.